# QUnit Test failing when it should be passing - JS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I have a javascript function where only 1 unit test is passing, when 2 of them should be passing, could someone point out the error. For some reason unit test *number 3* is not passing, but unit *test 4*, is?

**JavaScript:**

```
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// As soon as user scrolls down 20px show the scroll up button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};


function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    myBtn.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    myBtn.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**QUint Test:**

```
QUnit.test("3. Scroll button displayed if scrolled", function( assert ) {
  document.body.scrollTop = 22;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 22;

  scrollFunction();

  assert.equal(myBtn.style.display, "block", "This should be displayed.")
});

//4.
QUnit.test("4. Scroll button not displayed if  not scrolled", function( assert ) {
  document.body.scrollTop = 5;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 5;

  scrollFunction();

  assert.equal(myBtn.style.display, "none", "This should not be displayed.")
});
```